# Labeling shapes from Interpolation

Tags: qgis, labeling, interpolation

I would like to know if it is possible to automatically show the values of different color shapes on the shapes itself when interpolating some values. I use Qgis as a tool. You can see what I mean in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set you style by right clicking on the interpolated layer, clicking properties and choosing the style tab. Set the Render Type to Singleband pseudocolor. Press the + button to add categories until you have enough to cover the range of your interpolated data. Make sure you set the first value to 0, then go up in increments that you want your value contours to represent.

eg. for a range of values from 0-50 with 10m contours use 6 categories 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50

Next click Raster > Extraction > contour from the top menu and make the contours equal to the spacing of your categories above. Also make sure you tick the Attribute name box.

On the contour layer that's created, right click and choose properties. Click the labels tab, choose Show labels for this layer and label with the attribute selected when you made the contours.

You should now have what you are looking for